# How to pass a web element into the BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am getting web element like this

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Open Until')]")
```

Now I have to pass this element to soup to find it next & previous sibling. I am trying this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(elements,'html.parser')
```

What should i write

```
??? soup = BeautifulSoup(elements.source,'html.parser') ???
```

Please Suggest

Answer (score 4):

The elements returned by selenium of the form of `Selenium WebElements` and not in the form of `html`.
The `WebElements` need to be converted to HTML for `BeautifulSoup` to be able to parse it.

```py
# List of WebElements
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Open Until')]")

#iterate over all the elements found
for WebElement in elements:
   elementHTML = WebElement.get_attribute('outerHTML') #gives exact HTML content of the element
   elementSoup = BeautifulSoup(elementHTML,'html.parser')
   print(elementSoup)
```

Comment: I don't know why, but outerHTML and innerHTML don't seem to work for me right now

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to mix it and you can't, selenium also has method to get prev and next sibling, example

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://140f670e-5774-43b5-a1a5-c993f66fa51d.htmlpasta.com/')

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Open Until')]")
prevSibling = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//preceding-sibling::*')
nextSibling = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//following-sibling::*')

print(prevSibling.tag_name + ': ' + prevSibling.text)
print(element.tag_name + ': ' + element.text)
print(nextSibling.tag_name + ': ' + nextSibling.text)
driver.close()
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your answer. Can you please clarify it. I have both <p> elements above & below the "Open Until" element. What should i exactly write in x_Path.

Comment: prevSibling = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//preceding-sibling::p')
                                                                                                    nextSibling = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//following-sibling::p')                                 I have written in this way but unable to find it.

Comment: post your html snippet

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I am not able to add one.
So it should be:

> soup = BeautifulSoup(elements.parent.page_source,'html.parser')

or 
create soup directly from browser:

> soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')

and then search and get your elements in soup
There is no information about this in https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html   or https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors

Comment: I am getting the parent element through , rather i need it previous & next sibling. Can you please tell about the specific  solution.